# dynamic http response based on http request in java

Tags: java, http

We are building small test simulators that need to respond to restful requests injected into a platform based on content we inject into the message:

```
Example:  GET http://server/example-app/users
Content-Headers and/or query params = some value of pass with 200
Server respond with 200 and content


Example:  GET http://server/example-app/users
Content-Headers and/or query params = some value of fail with 400
Server respond with 400 and error
```

I am looking to see if anyone knows of an open source tool that would be of usefulness to inspect / parse the http request and figure out response based on the look-up criteria.  I'm sure I could write some parsers easily, but just interested if the community has used or knows of something that is available to do the parsing and response mappings.

Comment: Do you want to write a servlet that does this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](http://owasp.blogspot.dk/2013/01/owasp-zed-attack-proxy-v-200.html) covers your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is an excellent proxy to inspect code and perform filtering: http://fiddler2.com/